# How can I make a valid C++ alias template for std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, templates, unique-ptr

I want to make an alias template for `std::unique_ptr` that supplies my own deleter function.

`unique_ptr` has both a scalar and an array implementation, they're defined like this:

```
template <class T, class D = default_delete<T>>
class unique_ptr // scalar

template <class T, class D>
class unique_ptr<T[], D> // array
```

I'm running into trouble trying to override both the scalar and array versions of `unique_ptr`. It's easy to make an alias for just one version, like this:

```
template<class T>
struct Deleter {
    void operator()(T* ptr) { delete ptr; }
};

template<class T>
using my_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T Deleter<T>>;
```

But when I try to add a second alias, like this:

```
template<class T>
struct ArrayDeleter {
    void operator()(T* ptr) { delete [] ptr; }
};
template<class T>
using my_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T[], ArrayDeleter<T>>;
```

... I end up with compiler errors because "`my_unique_ptr`" is ambiguous.

My question is: **How can I create a single aliased name that works for both the array and scalar versions of `unique_ptr`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be trying to specialize a `using` declaration.  You may not.

```
template<class T>
struct my_unique_ptr_helper {
  using type = std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter<T>>;
};
template<class T>
struct my_unique_ptr_helper<T[]> {
  using type = std::unique_ptr<T[], ArrayDeleter<T>>;
};

template<class T>
using my_unique_ptr = typename my_unique_ptr_helper<T>::type;
```

Now this has disadvantages in that it blocks deduction rather completely.

We can fix this by moving the specialization elsewhere.

```
template<class T>
struct Deleter {
  void operator()(T* ptr) const {
    delete ptr;
  }
};
template<class T>
struct ArrayDeleter {
  void operator()(T* ptr) const {
    delete[] ptr;
  }
};
template<class T>
struct Deleter<T[]>:ArrayDeleter<T> {}; // inheritance
```

now:

```
template<class T>
using my_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter<T>>;
```

is simpler, and may permit more deduction of `T`.

Of course, this is all pretty pointless, but I presume your real `Deleter` isn't the same as `std::default_delete`.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I didn't need to make the ArrayDeleter struct at all. Instead, I created a general "template<t> Deleter" along with a Deleter specialization for T[].

Answer (score 2):

You should show us your `ArrayDeleter` but... are you sure that you can't solve your problem with a unique `using` and `std::conditional`?

I mean, something like

```
template <typename T>
using my_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T,
         typename std::conditional<std::is_array<T>::value,
                                   ArrayDeleter<T>,
                                   Deleter<T>>::type>;
```

**--- EDIT ---**

The OP say

> I've edited the question to include an example ArrayDeleter implementation

Not sure (I do a lot of errors with template array specializations) but I suppose that should work if you can modify `ArrayDeleter` as follows

```
template <typename>
struct ArrayDeleter;

template <typename T>
struct ArrayDeleter<T[]>
 { void operator()(T* ptr) { delete [] ptr; } };
```

Comment: I've edited the question to include an example ArrayDeleter implementation.

Comment: @DominicDosSantos - Answer improved; hope this helps